# how to get userid from $_session username

Tags: php, mysql, session

Is there a way to get a UserId in and sql table called Accounts based on a UserEmail also in Accounts? In php i have a page where people will login with a UserEmail from an Accounts table. this is all fine, but they need to write a review that is stored in a Reviews table and im having trouble pulling the UserId and putting it into the Review table.

Comment: @PeeHaa there is always another way!

Comment: And we're having trouble finding out why you are having trouble. Please show us what you've got and where you're hitting a wall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many ways; a very simple one is to just use an inline `SELECT` statement in the `INSERT` query. A very rough example, assuming you're using something like [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), might look like:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into review(score, user_id) values(?, select user_id from accounts where useremail = ?)");
$stmt->execute($score, $useremail);
```